# LESS - using BEM selector with extra class on parent to deviate

Tags: css, less

I have some markup that looks about like this -

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="card__icon">Icon</div>
   <div class="card__text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Which I am styling with a little LESS like so -

```
.card {
     &__icon {
        font-size: 1.75em;

         @media (min-width: 992px) {
              font-size: 2em;
          }
      }

       &__text {
          font-size: 1em;
       }
}
```

This works great - however the parent is getting toggled a class `.current` on it and I was trying to change one of the childrens styles using the same methods, but could not seem to get it working. I was trying this -

```
.card {
     &__icon {
        font-size: 1.75em;

         @media (min-width: 992px) {
              font-size: 2em;
          }
      }

       &__text {
          font-size: 1em;
       }

      &.current {
          // this is not working
          &__text {
              color: red;
          } 
     }
}
```

I can change the `&__text` inside the `&.current` to `.card__text` and it works fine - however I was wondering if there was a way I could keep the `&__text` syntax inside the `&.current` with using LESS. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the [parent selector &](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) expands to the whole parent nested rule, taking each nested rule parent as is and inserting it in place of `&, so in your case

```
.card {
     &.current {
         &__text {
             color: red;
         } 
     }
}
```

compiles to

```
.card.current__text {
    color: red;
}
```

which is not what we want, because class `current__text` does not exist. To avoid that you may rearrange the class selectors in your less rules like so:

```
.card {
     .current & {
         &__text {
             color: red;
         } 
     }
}
```

which compiles to:

```
.current .card__text {
    color: red;
}
```

A working example can be found in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PxQWWW)